# JavaScript: Is there anyway nowadays to open a new tab but keep the original tab as focussed?

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, tabs

This is not for any bad purpose. Our company's App has a preview page which opens in a new tab, but we want to have it open in new tab but keep the original tab(with our app) as focussed itself. User can switch between the two manually.

i tried this but didn't work.

```
const targetWindow = window.open(previewUrl);
targetWindow.blur();
window.focus();
```